# Install Outlook addin and exe

Tags: outlook, clickonce, outlook-addin, add-in

I'm currently using ClickOnce to install myapp.exe.  But now I've added Outlook 2007 addin support, myaddin.dll.

So, how can I install both exe and addin with ClickOnce.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can package them together per se. That's not supported (yet). But what you CAN do is deploy them to the webserver separately, and then have the desktop application invoke the install link for the Outlook Add-In when it runs. Just do a Process.Start("iexplore.exe", "http://myapp.com/myaddin.vsto")

Answer (score 1):

It might get complicated depending on which version of Office you're deploying for.

I think it can be done by adding the .exe project as a dependency of the addin project.  I read a little that said that's the way it's done, but haven't tried it personally.

Comment: It's for Outlook 2007.  I've changed the description. Thanks.

Comment: The addin install doesn't seem to install the exe well; no desktop icon, startup menu, etc...

Comment: Sorry that's not the solution.  ClickOnce doesn't serve a lot of my purposes when it comes to Outlook Addins.  Personally I'd suggest making it into a Windows Installer and using custom install actions.